# Transaction problem when attempting to commit

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, database-connection

I'm facing an issue when attempting to commit a row on my database.

[image: Api url]

I've got this following error when attepting to call this api url.

[image: Error]

I'm am setting headers like this

````
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const pool = require('../database/database');

const apiEndpoints = require('./endpoints/api');
const authEndpoints = require('./endpoints/auth');


const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const secret = 'IHDuhjdnoHODPdd526DDhkDKdDd2365d5d5BkgJSAdddsjxzpls23x32s';
app.use(session({
  secret,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  next();
});

const api = apiEndpoints.initEndpoints(pool);
const auth = authEndpoints.initEndpoints(pool);

app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/auth', auth);
const port = 4201;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});```


Can someone help me on this issue ? I'm unable to resolve it since a day now...
````

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a return statement after `res.json(err)` because you have already sent the response.

Comment: Thanks for reply; fix the stuffs you told me but still having the same issue... 

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client